# Wiring a compressor to an external building

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, subpanel

I have run 2,2,2,4 in conduit underground to a 100amp box. In the house the ground an neutral are bonded together but in the shed they are separated(isolated). I'm connecting a compressor through a disconnect box which only has L1, L2 and ground do I need a different box? Can the ground and neutrals be connected together like in the house? BTW the compressor is a 60 gallon 5HP 240V unit. I wanted a disconnect box so I can use a waterproof wip to the compressor.

Comment: Electrical requirements vary by location.  Where in the world are you?

Comment: Why would you want to connect ground and neutral together?

Comment: Does the compressor need 120V, or just 240V?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install an isolated neutral buss in the box connect the neutrals to this buss and the grounding conductors to the one that connects to the box case and you will be good to go. Most home stores and electrical supply stores have these isolated busses usually less than 10$ for a small one like you need, make sure if your box has 20 breaker openings to get a buss with close to that many holes, your 240v compressor may not require a neutral and most pumps, or other 240v only devices don't need a neutral.